# When to use clone() and how actually addAll() and add() works

Tags: java, arraylist, clone

I am using Java with MySQL.

There are about 60 transactions screens are there in my project. I had used `add()` and `addAll()` functions to copy an `ArrayList`.

For example:

```
 List<Bean> a1 = new ArrayList<Bean>(); // and add some value      
 List<Bean> a2 = new ArrayList<Bean>(); 
 a2.addAll(a1);
```

In this case:

1. In most of the screens, there is no any issue on `add()` or `addAll()` functions, but for some screens, if made change on list `a2` it also affects the `a1` list.
2. In these particular screens, clone concept (implements `Cloneable` interface) is used to get rid from it and its working fine.

According to my study, `add()` functions sets only reference to destinations list.

My doubts are:

1. Why `clone()` is required (For some cases only and not in all)?
2. What happens actually if we `add()` or  `addAll()` a list into another list?
3. Whether, `clone()` is mandatory for `add()` or `addAll()` methods or not?
4. Where we should use `clone()` and where shouldn't?
5. What should happen to list `a1` if we made any changes in list `a2`?

My final question:

When to use `clone()` or copy constructor and when we need not to use.
And in generic `List`, what should happen to source list if we made changes in   target list like above example.

Comment: No 5 should be answered by you. For 1, 3, 4 depends on the answer you provide for 5. For 2 [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: That is a lot of questions. Please narrow it down to one clear question.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted, and do use code formatting for text that is code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `addAll` adds all the references of the source List to the target List. It doesn't create copies of the instances these references refer to.

This is sufficient when the List holds references to immutable objects. If you add or remove elements from one of the Lists after the `addAll` operation, the changes won't be reflected in the other List.

If the List holds references to mutable objects, and you are modifying the state of those objects, you must create copies (either using clone or a copy constructor) if you don't want changes in one List to be reflected in the other List.

BTW, passing a List to `add` (instead of to `addAll`) will add a reference of the List to the target List. Unless the target List is a List of Lists, you shouldn't do that. `add` should accept a single element to be added to the List.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add a copy of the objects of one list to another list. As Eran said, simply calling add() or addAll() isn't going to be enough, since this copies references.

To add to Eran's answer - it sounds like you think calling clone() is going to solve your problem, but that's only true if you've implemented a custom clone function! The default clone() only creates a shallow copy, meaning that any references contained in the cloned object are copied over.

Generally speaking, I find copy constructors or factory methods much easier and safer than clone().