# How to copy list of one usertype of list of othertype?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have `List< SomePojo > firstList = new ArrayList< SomePojo >();`

//add 100 SomePojo objects to list.
Now the list has 100 objects.

If I create one more instance as below:

```
List<SomeOtherPojo> secondList = new ArrayList<SomeOtherPojo>();
```

Here, the SomePojo and SomeOtherPojo having the same public variable inside.
How to copy the content of firstList to secondList?
Is there any way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does `SomePojo`and `SomeOtherPojo` have acommon  interface or super class?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** use **[Collections.copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29)**

> Copies all of the elements from one list into another. After the operation, the index of each copied element in the destination list will be identical to its index in the source list. The destination list must be at least as long as the source list. If it is longer, the remaining elements in the destination list are unaffected.

```
 public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest,
                List<? extends T> src)
```

> **Parameters**:
>
> dest - The destination list.
>
> src - The source list.
>
> **Throws**:
>
> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the destination list is too small to contain the entire source List.
>
> `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the destination list's list-iterator does not support the set operation.

**sample code**

```
List< SomePojo > firstList = new ArrayList< SomePojo >();
List< SomeOtherPojo > secondList = new ArrayList< SomeOtherPojo >(firstList.size());

Collections.copy(secondList,firstList);
```

**2.** use **[ArrayList.addAll();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29)**

> It adds all the elements of specified Collection c to the current list.
>    Adds all of the specified elements to the specified collection.

```
ArrayList<ChatDataModel> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
firstList.add(model);
firstList.add(model4);
firstList.add(model2);
firstList.add(model3);
ArrayList<ChatDataModel> secondList = new ArrayList<>(firstList.size());
secondList.addAll(firstList);
```

Comment: Nice explaination +1

Comment: my pleasure @NileshRathod

Comment: Hi it show the below error.
error: method copy in class Collections cannot be applied to given types;
required: List<? super T>,List<? extends T>
found: List<SomeOtherPojo >,List<SomePojo >
reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
inferred: firstList 
upper bound(s): secondList ,Object
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>copy(List<? super T>,List<? extends T>)

Comment: my Model class are different in different list

Comment: @1911192110920 you can not add add diffent pojo class element in arralist can you share your both pojo class with question

Comment: @1911192110920 **the both arraylist pojo class must be same if you want to copy with collection.copy**

Comment: in the question itself i wrote this, this is what i need.

Comment: @1911192110920 you can't

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.ArrayList.addAll(Collection c) method appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's Iterator. The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress(implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection is this list, and this list is nonempty).

```
firstList.addAll(anotherListObjectWhoHasSamePojoType)
```

Comment: i have anotherListObjectWhoHasOtherPojoType.

Comment: then you need to Define the list of object type otherwise you will get the exception

Comment: Then u can use List<Object> thirdtList=new ArrayList<>;
thirdList.addAll(firstlist);
thirdList.addAll(secondList);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are ways.

```
firstArrayList.addAll((ArrayList<type>) secondArrayList.clone());

                          or

firstArrayList.addAll((ArrayList<type>) secondArrayList);
```

For Further Information regarding the Difference Between **clone** and **addAll** refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270168/when-to-use-clone-and-how-actually-addall-and-add-works)

Comment: compiler shows
clone() has protected access 'java.lang.Object'

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to:

```
secondList.addAll(firstList);
```

if SomePojo extends SomeOtherPojo

Otherwise you would need to - for example - convert SomePojo to SomeOtherPojo in a loop with some simple adapter class that copies the value of "same public variable" from SomePojo to new instance of SomeOtherPojo which then is added to the secondList.

More generic solution is possible with using reflection to get & set this  "same public variable".